# Painting square matrix in Java

Tags: java, matrix

I am practicing with Java swing. I've created a matrix as 2D array of `Rectangle2D` objects. I've set the `MouseListener` to paint the square which was clicked. I've set up the for loop which checks which square was clicked. When I click on a square it's painted in blue. The thing is, when I click on the other square, the first one turns white and the other turns blue. My question is, how to keep the color of the square which was first clicked?

Here's the code of `Matrica(Matrix)` class(It's in my native tongue, `crtanjeMatrice` means `drawMatrix` and `duzina` is `length`.

```
public class Matrica extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
Rectangle2D[][] matrica = new Rectangle2D[8][8];
Color boja = Color.white;
int a = 0;
int b = 0;

    public Matrica() {
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.clearRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        crtanjeMatrice(g2);
        g2.setColor(boja);
        g2.fill(matrica[a][b]);

    }




    private void crtanjeMatrice(Graphics2D g2){
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        int startX = 0;
        int startY =0;
        int duzina = 50;
        for(int i=0; i < matrica.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < matrica.length; j++){
                matrica[i][j] = new Rectangle2D.Double(startX,startY,duzina,duzina);
                g2.draw(matrica[i][j]);
                startX = startX + duzina;
            }
            startY = startY + duzina;
            startX = 0;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int m,n;
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        for(int i = 0; i < matrica.length; i++)
        for(int j =0; j < matrica.length; j++)
            if(matrica[i][j].contains(x, y)){
                boja = Color.blue;
                a = i;
                b = j;
                repaint();
            }
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant section of your code?

Comment: Can you show some code that does this? Otherwise, the solution is to store the color when clicked into a temporary variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently paint a single matrix cell in the `paint` method:

```
g2.fill(matrica[a][b]);
```

but you need to "remember" which rectangles have been clicked. To this end, a simple `List` can be used to store the indices of rectangles already clicked. A class based on the `Point` class offers a good means of storing *row-column* index information in the list.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);
   Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
   g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
   g2.clearRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
   crtanjeMatrice(g2);
   for (MyRowColumn index : indexList) { // MyRowColumn based on Point
     g2.setColor(Color.blue);
     g2.fill(matrica[index.x][index.y]);
   }
}
```

---

*Aside:*, don't use override `paint`, override `paintComponent` instead and remember to call  `super.paintComponent` to render child components.